# Loading Texture list with Texture2D dynamically from file at RunTime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have strings for the path to the Texture2D element I want to load from the List string that is filled dynamically from an XML file into the List Texture.

public List commands;
public List icons = new List();
void Awake()
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (string element in commands)
    {
        icons.Insert(i, icons[i].Resources.Load(element, Texture2D)); //error line
        i++;
    }

}

Here is what I have so far but I'm generating the following compiler errors in Unity:

> error CS1061: Type UnityEngine.Texture' does not contain a definition
>   for Resources' and no extension method Resources of type
>   `UnityEngine.Texture could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List.Insert(int,
>   UnityEngine.Texture)' has some invalid arguments
>
> error CS1503: Argument #2' cannot convert object' expression to type
>   `UnityEngine.Texture'

It seems I cannot use Resources.Load directly with the icons elements as I am attempting to do but I'm at a loss for how else to go about it.

Comment: Check out UnityAnswers, too :) ( http://answers.unity3d.com/ )

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string element in commands)
        {
         tex = (Texture2D) Resources.Load(element);
         icons.Add(tex);
        }
```

So I figured it out; above modifications are the changes.